# Си/qsort: сортирую массив ссылок на char*, получаю отсортированный массив, но при его выводе через процедуру он снова неотсортированный

Tags: c, char, qsort

в Си у меня есть values динамичный массив char*, я создаю динамический массив pVal ссылок на values и сортирую с помощью qsort и получаю отсортированный pVal, вывожу его, потом вычисляю позиции новых ссылок относительно старого массива и вывожу позиции отсортированных элементов. Для этого я из новой позиции элемента вычитаю ссылку на первый элемент. Я получаю правильный результат, но у меня сомнение потому что отсортированный массив pVal ведёт себя странно. Когда я передаю его в качестве параметра функции, которая его выводит на экран. Причем через функцию массив получается неотсортированный. Я перепробовал все варианты распечатывания: values,*pVal, pVal[0], &values, pVal - все они выводят мой неотсортированный массив. Куда девался мой отсортированный pVal? Спасибо.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int printArrayZZZ(char ***str, int amount)
{
    if (str)
    {
        for(int k = 0 ; k < amount; k++ ) 
            printf("%s ", (*str)[k] );
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int printArrayZZ(char **str, int amount)
{
    if (str)
    {
        for(int k = 0 ; k < amount; k++ ) 
            printf("%s ",str[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//array of char*
char** values;
//array of char**
char*** pVal;
int cmpfunc(const void * pa, const void * pb) 
{
const char* a = **(const char ***)pa;
const char* b = **(const char ***)pb;
return strcmp(a,b);
}
int main()
{
    //number of elements
    int n=10;
    //allocation for n-elem pVal
    pVal=malloc(n*sizeof(char**));
    values=malloc(n*sizeof(char*));

    //initialize values with different beginning to sort
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        asprintf(&(values[i]),"%dTest",7*i*i); 

    //Inicializing pVal to point to &values 
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            pVal[i] =values+i;

    //show array before sort
    int k;
    printf("Before sorting: \n");
    for( k = 0 ; k < n; k++ ) 
        printf("%s ", *pVal[k]);
    //do sorting
    qsort(pVal, n, sizeof(char**), cmpfunc);
    //show result pVal
    printf("\npVal After sorting :\n");
    for( k = 0 ; k < n; k++ ) 
        printf("%s ", *pVal[k]);

    printf("\nValues after sorting:\n");
    for( k = 0 ; k < n; k++ ) 
        printf("%s ", values[k]);

    printf("\nCalculation of sorted elements position in the initial array: \n");
    for( k = 0 ; k < n; k++ ) 
        printf(" %d", (int) (*(pVal+k) - values) );

    printf("\nPrint through function printArrayZZ values: \n");
    printArrayZZ(values,n);
    printf("\nPrint through function printArrayZZ *pVal: \n");
    printArrayZZ(*pVal,n);

    printf("\nPrint through function printArrayZZ pVal[0]: \n");
    printArrayZZ(pVal[0],n);
    
    printf("\nPrint through function printArrayz &values: \n");
    printArrayZZZ(&values,n);
    
    printf("\nPrint through function printArrayZZZ pVal: \n");
    printArrayZZZ(pVal,n);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Результат**

```
Массив строк values, ссылки на элементы которого буду сортировать:
Before sorting:                                                                                    
0Test 7Test 28Test 63Test 112Test 175Test 252Test 343Test 448Test 567Test                          
pVal массив ссылок на values After sorting :                                                                               
0Test 112Test 175Test 252Test 28Test 343Test 448Test 567Test 63Test 7Test                          
Values after sorting (is intacted, it is ok, because pointers to it was sorted):                                                                              
0Test 7Test 28Test 63Test 112Test 175Test 252Test 343Test 448Test 567Test                          
Calculation of sorted elements position in the initial array:                                      
 0 4 5 6 2 7 8 9 3 1   

Print values through function printArrayZZ values:                                                        
0Test 7Test 28Test 63Test 112Test 175Test 252Test 343Test 448Test 567Test                          

Print through function printArrayZZ *pVal(?!):                                                         
0Test 7Test 28Test 63Test 112Test 175Test 252Test 343Test 448Test 567Test                          

Print through function printArrayZZ pVal[0](?!):                                                       
0Test 7Test 28Test 63Test 112Test 175Test 252Test 343Test 448Test 567Test                          

Print through function printArrayZZZ &values (?!):                                                        
0Test 7Test 28Test 63Test 112Test 175Test 252Test 343Test 448Test 567Test                          

Print through function printArrayZZZ pVal(он же был отсорирован ?!) :                                                         
0Test 7Test 28Test 63Test 112Test 175Test 252Test 343Test 448Test 567Test
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> printf("\nPrint through function printArrayZZ values: \n");
> printArrayZZ(values,n);
> ```

Этот вызов просто печатает ваш неотсортированный массив `values`.

> ```
> printf("\nPrint through function printArrayZZ *pVal: \n");
> printArrayZZ(*pVal,n);
> ```

Этот вызов печатает массив из `char *`, который в памяти начинается с позиции `*pVal` (т.е. `pVal[0]`) и имеет длину `n`. В вашем случае значение `pVal[0]` после сортировки по-прежнему указывает на начало массива `values`, то есть этот вызов делает то же самое, что и предыдущий - он печатает ваш неотсортированный массив `values`.

Вам случайно повезло, что после сортировки `pVal[0]` осталось неизменным и указывает на начало `values`. Если бы сортировка поместила в `pVal[0]` какие-то другое значение, то `pVal[0]` указывало бы куда-то "в середину" `values` и попытка вывести `n` элементов с этого места привела бы к неопределенному поведению.

> ```
> printf("\nPrint through function printArrayZZ pVal[0]: \n");
> printArrayZZ(pVal[0],n);
> ```

`pVal[0]` и `*pVal` - это одно и то же. То есть этот вызов делает абсолютно то же самое, что и предыдущий. И ровно точно так же ошибочен/бессмыслен, т.е. держится на чистом везении.

> ```
> printf("\nPrint through function printArrayz &values: \n");
> printArrayZZZ(&values,n);
> ```

`ZZZ` версия функции делает то же самое, что и `ZZ` версия, но с дополнительным уровнем разыменования. То есть здесь вы снова просто печатаете массив `values`.

То есть все ваши вызовы просто печатают массив `values`, какие-то намеренно, какие-то случайно. Ни один из этих вызовов никак не использует содержимого массива `pVal` (кроме `pVal[0]`). Неудивительно, что отсортированного вывода они не печатают.

Comment: Спасибо, что указали на варианты, в которых мне "повезло". Это действительно грубые ошибки с потенциальным segmentation fault. Я нашёл "правильный" вывод массива pVal. 

void printArrayZZZ(char ***str, int amount)
{
    if (str)
        for(int k = 0 ; k < amount; k++ ) 
            printf("%s ", *(str)[k] );
} 
Соответственно вызов 
printArrayZZZ(pVal,n);  

Построить эту функцию я не смог, потому что ставил звёздочку разыменования не там, я ставил звёздочку под скобкой, а надо перед скобкой, так:
*(str)[k]
Тогда получалось разыменование массива, а потом брался индекс - ошибка